# Stripe Account Link

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Im using Stripe Account link API's response url to open stripe connect form and get details of customer

Stripe Account link code:

```
stripe->accountLinks->create([
  'account' => 'acct_1DDbifHk4p1Ao4HJ',
  'refresh_url' => 'https://example.com?completed=0',
  'return_url' => 'https://example.com?completed=1',
  'type' => 'account_onboarding',
]);
```

in stripe connect form i have 'Save for later' option you can see in image

[image: Strip connect form]

in account link api, im completed parameter to find whether the form is filled or not.

1. if completed=0 , form is not filled so that i can once again redirect them to form to fill
2. if completed =1, form is filled

but if they press 'Save for Later' then also ir return completed = 1 i.e, returnurl is invoked

my question is how can i differentiate between completed form and partially completed stripe connect form ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use the /v1/accounts endpoint to retrieve the user’s account and check for charges_enabled. If the account isn’t fully onboarded, provide UI prompts to allow the user to continue onboarding later. The user can complete their account activation through a new account link (generated by your integration). You can check the state of the details_submitted parameter on their account to see if they’ve completed the onboarding process.

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#span-classstepstep-5span-handle-users-that-have-not-completed-onboarding